# Not sure about NFC errors with techlist

Tags: nfc, open-nfc

I would like to ask what is the problem for this part when i am creating with nfc_tech_filter.xml

This is my code

```
    Can't determine type for tag '<tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    </tech-list>'
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
        <tech-list>
            <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
            <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
            <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        </tech-list>

    ``</resources>
```

Comment: Hmm, xml looks ok, not seem this type of error message, one thought is that Implementation of the MifareUltralight on a Android NFC device is optional, try removing the MifareUltralight to see if your device has not implemented this tag type.

Comment: After removing Mifare Ultralight is still unavailable, im using android Samsung A51 which it's NFC chip is able to run MifareUltralight and NTAG only, so for Mifare Classic i didn't implemented in the code

Comment: Just to confirm the xml file is in the app\src\main\res\xml folder? And not next to the AndroidManifest.xml