# check if my NFC codings are correct for storing user data with getting user details into edit user details with storing data on NFC chip

Tags: java, android, nfc

I would like to ask of what is the reason of my coding that made my app cannot be run at all, at first it says of  is not verified
[Not sure about NFC errors with techlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76300799/not-sure-about-nfc-errors-with-techlist?noredirect=1#comment134559291_76300799)
After I move techfilter to `/values` file and started to run, it came out this error and pressed retry to install back and it comes with the same issue...

Launching 'app' on samsung SM-A515F.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:

> [0] 'D:----NFC
> Projects\LayoutAndDesignNFC\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'

Installation failed due to: `Connection refused: connect`
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices

EditProfileActivity.java

```
package com.example.layoutanddesignnfc;

class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editName, editEmail, editUsername, editPassword;
    Button saveButton;
    String nameUser, emailUser, usernameUser, passwordUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseDatabase User;
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        editName = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editUsername = findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);


        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isNameChanged() || isPasswordChanged() || isEmailChanged()) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "No Changes Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFc is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private boolean isNameChanged() {
        if (!nameUser.equals(editName.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(usernameUser).child("name").setValue(editName.getText().toString());
            nameUser = editName.getText().toString();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean isEmailChanged() {
        if (!emailUser.equals(editEmail.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(usernameUser).child("email").setValue(editEmail.getText().toString());
            emailUser = editEmail.getText().toString();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean isPasswordChanged() {
        if (!passwordUser.equals(editPassword.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(usernameUser).child("password").setValue(editPassword.getText().toString());
            passwordUser = editPassword.getText().toString();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void showData(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        nameUser = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        emailUser = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        passwordUser = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        editName.setText(nameUser);
        editEmail.setText(emailUser);
        editUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        editPassword.setText(passwordUser);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        enableNfcForegroundDispatch();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        disableForegroundDispatch();
    }

    private void enableNfcForegroundDispatch(){
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        IntentFilter[] intentFilters= new IntentFilter[]{
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED),
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
        };
        String[][] techLists = new String[][]{new String[]{Ndef.class.getName()}};

        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, techLists);

    }

    private void disableForegroundDispatch(){
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleNfcIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleNfcIntent(Intent intent){
        String action= intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (tag != null) {
                Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
                if (ndef != null) {
                    try {
                        ndef.connect();
                        NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
                        if (ndefMessage != null) {
                            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
                            for (NdefRecord record : records) {
                                String payload = readTextFromNdefRecord(record);
                                // Do something with the payload
                                Toast.makeText(this, "NFC Tag Content: " + payload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        ndef.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading NFC tag", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NDEF is not supported by this NFC tag", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String readTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] payload= record.getPayload();

        String textEncoding=((payload[0] & 0*80) ==0)? "UTF-8": "utf-16" ;

        //get language code
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0x3F;
        String languageCode= new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

        //get payload
        String textPayload= new String(payload, 1+ languageCodeLength, payload.length - 1 - languageCodeLength, textEncoding);

        return textPayload;
    }
}
```

UserProfileActivity.java

```
  package com.example.layoutanddesignnfc;
  

    public class ProfileActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
    private boolean isWriteMode=false;
    private String dataToWrite="Your data to be written in Tag";
    TextView profileName, profileEmail, profileUsername, profilePassword;
    TextView titleName, titleUsername;
    Button editProfile, btnLogout, btnNfcTag;
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_NFC=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile1);
        profileName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        profileEmail = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profileUsername = findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        profilePassword = findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        titleName = findViewById(R.id.titleName);
        titleUsername = findViewById(R.id.titleUsername);
        editProfile = findViewById(R.id.editProfile);
        btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.Logout);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        showAllUserData();

    // Initialize NFC adapter
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not supported on this device", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        // Create a PendingIntent for NFC events
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()), 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        editProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                passUserData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity1.this, 
    EditProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity1.this, LoginActivity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    //BTN NFC TAG
        Button btnNfcTag = findViewById(R.id.buttonNFC);
        btnNfcTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity1.this, 
    EditProfileActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        enableNfcForegroundDispatch();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        disableNfcForegroundDispatch();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleNfcIntent(intent);
    }
    private void enableNfcForegroundDispatch() {
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
    private void disableNfcForegroundDispatch() {
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    private void handleNfcIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (tag != null) {
                if (isWriteMode) {
                    writeDataToNfcTag(tag);
                } else {
                    readDataFromNfcTag(tag);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void writeDataToNfcTag(Tag tag) {
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = createNdefMessage(dataToWrite);
        if (ndefMessage != null) {
            try {
                Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
                if (ndef != null) {
                    ndef.connect();
                    if (ndef.isWritable()) {
                        ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Data written to NFC tag", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC tag is read-only", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    ndef.close();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "NDEF is not supported by this NFC tag", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error writing data to NFC tag", e);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create NDEF message", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private void readDataFromNfcTag(Tag tag) {
        try {
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef != null) {
                ndef.connect();
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
                if (ndefMessage != null) {
                    NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
                    if (records != null && records.length > 0) {
                        NdefRecord record = records[0];
                        String data = parseNdefRecord(record);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Read data from NFC tag: " + data, 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // TODO: Handle the read data as needed
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF records found on the NFC tag", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No NDEF message found on the NFC tag", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                ndef.close();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "NDEF is not supported by this NFC tag", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error reading data from NFC tag", e);
        }
    }
    private NdefMessage createNdefMessage(String data) {
        NdefRecord record = createTextRecord(data);
        if (record != null) {
            return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{record});
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String text) {
        byte[] languageBytes;
        byte[] textBytes;
        try {
            languageBytes = "en".getBytes("US-ASCII");
            textBytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int languageLength = languageBytes.length;
            int textLength = textBytes.length;

            byte[] payload = new byte[1 + languageLength + textLength];
            payload[0] = (byte) (languageLength & 0x1F);
            System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, payload, 1, languageLength);
            System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + languageLength, textLength);

            return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new 
    byte[0], payload);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating text record", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String parseNdefRecord(NdefRecord record) {
        if (record.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(record.getType(), 
    NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
            try {
                byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
                String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 0x80) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
                int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0x1F;
                String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, 
    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
                String text = new String(payload, 1 + languageCodeLength, payload.length - 1 
    - languageCodeLength, textEncoding);
                return text;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing NDEF record", e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void showAllUserData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nameUser = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String emailUser = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        String usernameUser = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        String passwordUser = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        titleName.setText(nameUser);
        titleUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        profileName.setText(nameUser);
        profileEmail.setText(emailUser);
        profileUsername.setText(usernameUser);
        profilePassword.setText(passwordUser);
    }

    public void passUserData() {
        String userUsername = profileUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        Query checkUserDatabase = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userUsername);
        checkUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    String nameFromDB = 
    snapshot.child(userUsername).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String emailFromDB = 
    snapshot.child(userUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String usernameFromDB = 
    snapshot.child(userUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);
                    String passwordFromDB = 
    snapshot.child(userUsername).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity1.this, 
    EditProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("email", emailFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                    intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String scanResult = data.getStringExtra("scanResult");
            if (scanResult.equals("success")) {
                // Display user's information from User Profile.xml
                showAllUserData();
            } else if (scanResult.equals("unknown")) {
                // Handle unknown NFC tag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HelperClass.java

```
package com.example.layoutanddesignnfc;

    public class HelperClass {
    String name, email, username, password;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public HelperClass(String name, String email, String username, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public HelperClass() {
    }
}
```